# Linux From Scratch error in Bison-3.0.4 'make check'

Tags: c++, linux, bison, flex-lexer, linux-from-scratch

So I'm following the **Linux From Scratch** book and am in chapter [5.17 Bison-3.0.4](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter05/bison.html).

The book instructs us to do a `make check` after `make` to test the result of the compiled Bison package.

Initially, I was getting the following error:

```
make[3]: Entering directory `/sources/bison-3.0'
  LEX      examples/calc++/calc++-scanner.cc
  CXX      
examples/calc++/examples_calc___calc__-calc++-scanner.o
g++: error: ./examples/calc++/calc++-scanner.cc: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** 
[examples/calc++/examples_calc___calc__-calc++-scanner.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/sources/bison-3.0'
make[2]: *** [check-am] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/sources/bison-3.0'
make[1]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/sources/bison-3.0'
make: *** [check] Error 2
```

But got a solution on [this website](http://lists.linuxfromscratch.org/pipermail/lfs-support/2013-November/045898.html). Which told me to do the following before issuing `make check`:

```
cp Makefile Makefile.bak
sed -i '/calc++/d' Makefile
make check
```

This solved the issue and all checks were getting a green `ok` apart from the following three `FAILED` checks:

```
430: Variants lalr1.cc parse.assert api.token.constructor FAILED (c++.at:374)
431: Variants lalr1.cc parse.assert api.token.constructor api.token.prefix={TOK_} FAILED (c++.at:375)
432: Variants lalr1.cc parse.assert api.token.constructor api.token.prefix={TOK_} %locations FAILED (c++.at:376)
```

I tried searching on Google but get nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please read the site guidelines, you need to provide a minimal but complete example. Also, before tagging your question with anything, make sure that tag actually applies.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt -The book I linked is the example. I unfortunately can't type the entire book as that would be too long. Hence why I linked it instead.... The question was aimed at those familiar with Linux From Scratch. Hence why I used the tag `lfs`. This is as specific as I could get.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt - I also put 'Linux From Scratch' in the question title. I don't know how much more specific I have to be (don't mean to sound rude btw)

Comment: I'm also not trying to be rude. However, firstly, remove tags from the topic, they bloat it up unnecessarily. Then, read the description of the "linux" tag: Nothing here is specific to Linux, it could occur on any other system, too. OTOH, I'm guessing a bit, because you don't have a minimal example, and that's what is really missing. Take the code and extract one. This makes sure that all necessary info but no superfluous info is present. Putting a link out and asking others to locate the relevant info there simply makes your question off-topic according to the SO rules.

Comment: The message you cited seems to stated a package was missing. Did you install `flex` like detailed in [the follow up](http://lists.linuxfromscratch.org/pipermail/lfs-support/2013-November/045899.html)?

Comment: @jww - Thank you for commenting. I just installed `flex`, I'm assuming I'll have to recompile every package again.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I think you misunderstood what the question is about. The OP did not write any code, so there's nothing to post a minimal example of. The OP is trying to build a Linux system from scratch and as part of that is compiling bison, which is apparently failing at the `make check` stage.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt it's clear you know nothing about linux from scratch, so please don't comment. there is nothing wrong with this question.

Comment: Pretty arrogant to assume that from me, @rsm, effectively you call me too stupid to follow a link. Still, SO is about programming-related questions. There's code involved, sure, but the OP isn't doing the programming. To some extent one could argue that all they do is follow predefined steps, like playing a game, and you wouldn't call that programming either, would you? This is basically a bug report concerning some program (with parts of the program being instructions executed manually), but SO is the wrong place to ask support questions!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's common mistake. As stated in [Chapter 4.6. About the Test Suites](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter04/abouttestsuites.html):

> Experience has shown that there is little to be gained from running
>   the test suites in Chapter 5. There can be no escaping the fact that
>   the host system always exerts some influence on the tests in that
>   chapter, often causing inexplicable failures. Because the tools built
>   in Chapter 5 are temporary and eventually discarded, we do not
>   recommend running the test suites in Chapter 5 for the average reader.
>   **The instructions for running those test suites are provided for the
>   benefit of testers and developers, but they are strictly optional.**

Solution is simple - don't run tests for packages compiled in Chapter 5. They will fail and it doesn't mean anything. Tests are important in Chapter 6 when you build your real system.

Comment: Thank you for answering :).  I just realised tests weren't necessary in Chapter 5.